# Pass imported functions to another package in Perl

Tags: perl, oop

i'am trying to pass imported functions to another created package.
Maybe someone could help me :)

```
package Person;

use JSON;    # i want to pass functions from this module to the package 'Employee'

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = {
       _name => "No Name",
   };
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}

sub setName {
    my ($self, $name) = @_;
    $self->{_name} = $name;
}

sub getName {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{_name};
}

1;
```

Now i want to use functions from the JSON Package inside this module.

```
package Employee;
use JSON qw( encode_json ); # This works, thx to everybody 

our @ISA = qw(Person);

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = Person->new();

    encode_json({a=>1}); # this works now

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
1;
```

I would be nice, if someone could give me some hints. 
Thanks to everybody

Comment: just call `use JSON` after your `package` declaration

Comment: I don't want to call 'use JSON' inside the 'Employee.pm'

Comment: Why not make a method, like `_encode_json` which then just calls `encode_json` and call that method in `Employee` instead? Silently/blindly exporting methods to classes that inherit from your class is a horrible idea.

Comment: Hint: to use exported functions from the JSON module inside another package, call `use JSON` from inside that package.

Comment: Well, `use JSON;` in each package that uses functions provided by that module is the way to get them. Why don't you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking how to place `encode_json` in the `Employee` namespace. To do that, add the following after `package Employee;`:

```
use JSON qw( encode_json );
```

Comment: (Or just `use JSON;` if you want to import all the default exports. However, I consider not listing your imports to be a bad practice.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm also not sure why in the comment the OP said that he/she cannot (or does not want) put "use JSON" in the Employee package. Maybe because the Employee package file (Employee.pm) is written by someone else and cannot be modified.

Note that in Perl you can "open the Employee" package from any other code written in any file. So in your main script or the Person package file or wherever, you can do:

```
{ package Employee; use JSON; }
```

Comment: You have to make sure that the Perl compiler encounters that line before Employee.pm is loaded, or you could get compile-time errors. This is so fragile that modifying unrelated files could cause the code to suddenly give compile-time errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely could not add `use JSON` to the Employee class because you were not sure what encoding you'd need to use, then you could pass a code reference into `new`:

```
# in Person.pm
my $e = Employee->new(\&JSON::encode_json);

# in Employee.pm
sub new {
  my($class, $encoder) = @_;
  ...
  $self->{_encoded} = $encoder->($value_to_encode);
  ...
  return $self;
}
```

Again, the *only* reason you'd want to do this is if you dynamically needed to change which encoder you wanted to use. The solution you've adopted -- `use JSON qw(encode_json)` -- is the right one if you want that one function and won't need to change it.

Comment: You forgot the `\ ` necessary to pass a code reference to a named sub, the current code will just call it and pass the return value (along with a couple other oddities due to using `&` to call a subroutine)

Comment: So I did, thanks. Fixing that. (I have been writing Go lately and am used to mentioning a function to get a reference to it!)